# WAMP Server connection refuesed from Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, apache, android-asynctask, wampserver

I am trying to connect to localhost WAMP Apache server from my android Emulator. But connections is getting refused. All the details provided below. Please help me out.

**1) Android Logcat:**

Error:

```
12-11 01:56:05.880  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:80 refused
```

Complete Error message:

```
12-11 01:56:04.845  10346-10353/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 178.509ms

12-11 01:56:04.947  10346-10369/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

12-11 01:56:04.947  10346-10369/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad921ae0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

12-11 01:56:05.010  10346-10357/com.revu.revuappforcollege I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2091(146KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 1410KB/1922KB, paused 3.545ms total 623.566ms

12-11 01:56:05.015  10346-10346/com.revu.revuappforcollege I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-11 01:56:05.143  10346-10353/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 74.530ms

12-11 01:56:05.840  10346-10346/com.revu.revuappforcollege I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-11 01:56:05.880  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:80 refused

12-11 01:56:05.880  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:193)

12-11 01:56:05.880  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)

12-11 01:56:05.947  10346-10369/com.revu.revuappforcollege E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabfb9990

12-11 01:56:06.161  10346-10353/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 82.626ms

12-11 01:56:06.493  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)

12-11 01:56:06.493  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)

12-11 01:56:06.493  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)

12-11 01:56:06.493  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)

12-11 01:56:06.646  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)

12-11 01:56:06.646  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at com.revu.revuappforcollege.Activity1$readNFCTag.doInBackground(Activity1.java:336)

12-11 01:56:06.718  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at com.revu.revuappforcollege.Activity1$readNFCTag.doInBackground(Activity1.java:292)

12-11 01:56:06.718  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)

12-11 01:56:06.718  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

12-11 01:56:07.136  10346-10353/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 57.421ms
12-11 01:56:07.230  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)

12-11 01:56:07.230  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)

12-11 01:56:07.230  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)

12-11 01:56:07.230  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

12-11 01:56:07.230  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 80): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)

12-11 01:56:07.269  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)

12-11 01:56:07.269  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)

12-11 01:56:07.269  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)

12-11 01:56:07.269  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
12-11 01:56:07.269  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:124)

12-11 01:56:07.270  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
12-11 01:56:07.270  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
12-11 01:56:07.270  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
 12-11 01:56:07.270  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
 12-11 01:56:07.270  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
12-11 01:56:07.270  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
 12-11 01:56:07.270  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
12-11 01:56:07.270  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/System.err﹕ ... 19 more



12-11 01:56:07.506  10346-32019/com.revu.revuappforcollege E/AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.revu.revuappforcollege, PID: 10346
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:345)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:101)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:259)
        at com.revu.revuappforcollege.Activity1$readNFCTag.doInBackground(Activity1.java:353)
        at com.revu.revuappforcollege.Activity1$readNFCTag.doInBackground(Activity1.java:292)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-11 01:56:07.546  10346-10353/com.revu.revuappforcollege W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 13.659ms
```

**2) I have added Permissionin Manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**3) Android code:**

```
class readNFCTag extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
  private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity1.this);
  InputStream is;
  String result;

  protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.e("BP4", "In onPreExecute");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
    progressDialog.show();
    result = "";
    is = null;

    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
        readNFCTag.this.cancel(true);
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    Log.e("BP5", "In doInBackground");

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // HttpPost httpPost = new
    // HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/SomeName/Details.php");
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:80/AllainanceCanteen/NFCTagDetails.php");

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    try {

      Log.e("BP6", "In doInBackground2");
      param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NFCTagNumber", Integer.toString(NFCTagNumber)));
      Log.e("BP8", "In doInBackground2");
      httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
      Log.e("BP9", "In doInBackground2");

      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
      }
      Log.e("BP19", "In doInBackground: " + NFCTagNumber);
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
      Log.e("BP10", "In doInBackground3");
      HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
      Log.e("BP7", "In doInBackground3");
      // read content
      is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
      // Log.e("####log_tag2", "End Here" + e.toString());

      // Log.e("!!!!log_tag", "Start Here");
      e.printStackTrace();
      // Log.e("***log_tag", "END HERE 2");

      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cannot connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      this.progressDialog.dismiss();
      closeActivity();
    }
    try {

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      while (null != (line = br.readLine())) {
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
      }
      is.close();
      result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

      Log.e("log_tag2", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
      this.progressDialog.dismiss();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid NFC Communication!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      closeActivity();
    }

    return null;

  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

    Log.e("Log_info", "REsults are: " + result + " End HERE");

    JSONObject Jarray = new JSONObject();

    try {

      try {
        Jarray = new JSONObject(result);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Communication!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        closeActivity();

      }

      if ((result.isEmpty()) || (result == null)) {

        // text.setText("Search Results Not found!!");
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        closeActivity();

      } else {

        Log.e("BP7", "In doInBackground");
        for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {

          Log.e("Log_info", "Results2 are: " + Jarray.toString() + " End HERE");
          // text_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
          seekReview = Jarray.getString("ProductName");

          addWidgetsToLayout();

          this.progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

      }
    } catch (Exception e) {

      Log.e("log_tag3", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot connect to server!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      closeActivity();
    }

  }
}
```

**4) httpd.conf file Permissions are:**

```html
*Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Files ".ht*">
        Require all granted
</Files>*
```

**5) No other software is using port 80**

**6) I also turnned off the Windows firewall and no anti virus in system**.

**7) I also tried with port 8080, but there is same problem**

Comment: You cannot put a Toast in doInBackground or dismiss a progress dialog or close an activity. Such things have to be done in onPostExecute. So return null from a catch or a suitable error message like e.getMessage(). You log a thousend times but forget this one who tells you the reason for a catch.

Comment: Remove the StrictMode!!!!!!

Comment: Hi, I have removed Toast and StrictMode from doInBackground method. But still get same error like "12-11 02:24:34.538 23952-24112/com.revu.revu E/log_tag﹕ Error in http connection org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to 10.0.2.2:80 refused" after " HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);"

Comment: Please adapt your code here too. So we know where we have to look at.